# Add JSON object to DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object  that I'm getting as a response to an AJAX call:

```
{ "Score": 5, "OS": "Windows 7" }
```

I want to add it to a div but the following does not work, `data.OS` or `data.Score` just return as undefined

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '/details',
     data: JSON.stringify(IP), 
     contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',   
     success: function(data) {

        $('#OSdetails').append('<div id="details">Operating System: ' + data.OS + '</div>');

     }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you `console.log(data)`, you get exactly `Object { "Score": 5, "OS": "Windows 7" }`?

Comment: What was the requested data type in your Ajax call? If you set it to JSON it will convert automatically. Please show your Ajax call code

Comment: I updated the code. And yes GG I do.

Comment: If you use firebug then you can debug the success method and see what paramaters the data paramater has.

Comment: Can you add the all ajax code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
     dataType: 'JSON',         <==== THIS IS MISSING
     type: "POST",
     url: '/details',
     data: JSON.stringify(IP), 
     contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',   
     success: function(data) {
```

`dataType` specifies the expected data type and allows for automated conversion

Comment: Just a moment, I need to re-setup my server and then I will verify.

Comment: Pretty common error. You specified the type of data being send, but not what was expected back.

Comment: Worked great, sorry for the slow response. Was having some server issues.